# Combination of applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to know if it was possible to import one or more applications in another application .

What I have to do :

- I have created a new application
- In this application I import the .xcodeproj of the second application
- When I run any application error

But I am able to access the main storyboard application but without success yet.

In fact the basic app will basically serve as a menu with the possibility to launch 2 see 3 applications to be integrated directly in it to actually consolidate while a single application.

I used this code to try to access the storyboard (found in .xcodeproj ) but without success.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UIViewController *detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HOMESB"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't really think that this is going to be a good idea since will not have multiple (meaningful) calls to the app delegate. But if you just want to import code and the UI it should be possible. Can you pls post the error message

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: these is the error :
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/MGSnakeEater/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B37B0A80-8C7E-4F2D-B557-610010CF7EC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5B457357-2B97-43FD-A5EB-C66E9241E66C/complet.app>